# Call service when pressing a button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony-2.3

I would like to use [dismissable Bootstrap alerts](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#alerts-dismissable) to display some help messages to my users.

Moreover, I would like them to be able to definitively dismiss each alert, one by one. The "database" part is already done and works properly (a `User` entity, a `Message` entity, a Many-To-Many relationship inbetween to list which `User` wants to always dismiss which `Message`).

Now I would like to have the following beheavior: when a User (logged in, of course) clics on the `dismiss` button (an "X" in this case), this hides the Bootstrap alert (=normal behavior) **and call a service** which adds a new line in my User-Message join table, **without reloading the current page**.

How should I do that? Using TWIG? JS?

Any other suggestion to achieve the same final result (i.e. provide hideable help message to users)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Javascript to launch an ajax request when clicking the close button.

Here it is in jQuery:

```
$(".close").click(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: 'your-url.php',
     type: 'post',
     data: {},
     success: function (data) {
        alert('done!')
    }
   });
});
```

That way you can your page will not reload but you will be able to do some stuff server-side, e.g. insert a row in your User-Message join table.

Comment: Exactly what I needed, works like a charm, quick answer: thanks a lot man!!